# Azure REST Api to create classic deployment model storage account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-deployment, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to create Azure storage account kind: `Storage (classic)` via REST APi.

When I'm sending this request:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{{name}}?api-version=2019-04-01
```

with body:

```
{
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_GRS"
  },
  "kind": "Storage",
  "location": "eastus2"
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but my created storage is kind: `Storage (general purpose v1)`.

I've tried to send request with `Microsoft.ClassicStorage` like so:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{{name}}?api-version=2016-11-01
```

same body as before (and also tried without `"kind"` parameter), and I get response: `400 Bad Request`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidStorageAccountRequest",
        "message": "The storage account '{{validname}}' request is invalid."
    }
}
```

Any idea what should be placed in request body? Or is it possible to create Storage(classic) via REST API or by c# code?

Comment: The error shows the storage name is invalid. So what is the name? You can make the check.

Comment: Not related but why would you like to create a classic storage account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution (.NET)

*Storage Account (classic)* doesn't have option to "Export template", but it can be found in another place, as follow:

1. Go to https://portal.azure.com
2. Create a resource (Storage Account)
3. Click on "Choose classic deployment model"
4. Chose tab "Review + create"
5. Click "Download a template for automation"

You should get two JSON files:

- parameter.json (here you can change parameters values):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "westeurope"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "testtemplate"
        },
        "accountType": {
            "value": "Standard_GRS"
        }
    }
}
```

- template.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "accountType": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2016-11-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "[parameters('accountType')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

And now to deploy it, you just need to past it below, with all private credentials
(code is copied from *Storage Account kind V2*  "Export template" tab)

```
// Requires the following Azure NuGet packages and related dependencies:
// package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Authorization" version="2.0.0"
// package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" version="1.4.0-preview"
// package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.8-preview"

using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PortalGenerated
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is a helper class for deploying an Azure Resource Manager template
    /// More info about template deployments can be found here https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/?LinkID=733371
    /// </summary>
    class DeploymentHelper
    {
        string subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id";
        string clientId = "your-service-principal-clientId";
        string clientSecret = "your-service-principal-client-secret";
        string resourceGroupName = "resource-group-name";
        string deploymentName = "deployment-name";
        string resourceGroupLocation = "resource-group-location"; // must be specified for creating a new resource group
        string pathToTemplateFile = "path-to-template.json-on-disk";
        string pathToParameterFile = "path-to-parameters.json-on-disk";
        string tenantId = "tenant-id";

        public async void Run()
        {
            // Try to obtain the service credentials
            var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            // Read the template and parameter file contents
            JObject templateFileContents = GetJsonFileContents(pathToTemplateFile);
            JObject parameterFileContents = GetJsonFileContents(pathToParameterFile);

            // Create the resource manager client
            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(serviceCreds);
            resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            // Create or check that resource group exists
            EnsureResourceGroupExists(resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName, resourceGroupLocation);

            // Start a deployment
            DeployTemplate(resourceManagementClient, resourceGroupName, deploymentName, templateFileContents, parameterFileContents);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a JSON file from the specified path
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathToJson">The full path to the JSON file</param>
        /// <returns>The JSON file contents</returns>
        private JObject GetJsonFileContents(string pathToJson)
        {
            JObject templatefileContent = new JObject();
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(pathToJson))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
                {
                    templatefileContent = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                    return templatefileContent;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures that a resource group with the specified name exists. If it does not, will attempt to create one.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceManagementClient">The resource manager client.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupName">The name of the resource group.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupLocation">The resource group location. Required when creating a new resource group.</param>
        private static void EnsureResourceGroupExists(ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient, string resourceGroupName, string resourceGroupLocation)
        {
            if (resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CheckExistence(resourceGroupName) != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating resource group '{0}' in location '{1}'", resourceGroupName, resourceGroupLocation));
                var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup();
                resourceGroup.Location = resourceGroupLocation;
                resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, resourceGroup);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Using existing resource group '{0}'", resourceGroupName));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts a template deployment.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceManagementClient">The resource manager client.</param>
        /// <param name="resourceGroupName">The name of the resource group.</param>
        /// <param name="deploymentName">The name of the deployment.</param>
        /// <param name="templateFileContents">The template file contents.</param>
        /// <param name="parameterFileContents">The parameter file contents.</param>
        private static void DeployTemplate(ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient, string resourceGroupName, string deploymentName, JObject templateFileContents, JObject parameterFileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Starting template deployment '{0}' in resource group '{1}'", deploymentName, resourceGroupName));
            var deployment = new Deployment();

            deployment.Properties = new DeploymentProperties
            {
                Mode = DeploymentMode.Incremental,
                Template = templateFileContents,
                Parameters = parameterFileContents["parameters"].ToObject<JObject>()
            };

            var deploymentResult = resourceManagementClient.Deployments.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, deploymentName, deployment);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Deployment status: {0}", deploymentResult.Properties.ProvisioningState));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try by changing your request body to something like the following:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "accountType": "Standard-GRS"
  },
  "location": "eastus2"
}
```

The account kind for classic storage accounts are different than those of new storage accounts. They are `Standard-GRS`, `Standard-LRS`, `Standard-RAGRS`, `Standard-ZRS` and `Premium-LRS`.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this kind of issue before and it seems to be because of the name you are giving to your storage account but for me the invalid code was the one bellow:

Code=AccountNameInvalid

> It is not a valid storage account name. Storage account name must be 
>   between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only.

you can check it out in the Azure documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-storage-account-name-errors).

Comment: I've just type example of {{name}}, but it's valid due to the fact I've created Storage(v2) with same {{name}}

Comment: I got it but I meant the name you're giving to the storage account, like I was trying to use capital letters.

Comment: Check the azure mode because for classic deployment it should be [asm](https://www2.linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/17186-understanding-key-difference-between-azure-asm-and-azure-arm/) but I was thinking it was a name issue because of the message you got **"The storage account '{{validname}}' request is invalid."**